# UISCrollview+enable left side scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView. I want to implement an infinite left side-scrolling effect. How can this be possible?

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width/7;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    Lbl_Rate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"   pagenumber==>%d",page ];  
    int p=page%10;
    if(p==0){ 
        page=1;
        SCrl_Wheel.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }
}
```

I had trid to set contentoffset by  `SCrl_Wheel.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);`

But it is not actually setting `contentoffset.x=0;`

And this is making :-`[SCrl_Wheel setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];` my loop as infinite loop.

Comment: What do u mean by left side ??

Comment: You can use the `contentOffset` property of the `UIScrollView` to achieve this.
For sample codes and details check these links: [Link 1](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling) [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693097/infinite-uiscrollview-in-both-direction/8319984#8319984) [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845789/how-to-create-a-uiscrollview-of-infinite-scrolling)

Comment: @Gill I want to implment the horizontal scrolling.I had give [SCrl_Wheel setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100000,0)]; It allow me to scroll on right side.But not allowing me to scroll on left side

Answer (score 1):

Add this `setContentSize:` to your code.

```
[SCrl_Wheel setContentSize:CGSizeMake(-100000,50)];
```

Now it would scroll like the way you want to and why hav u added your y = 0 ?? then the **height** of the `UIScrollView` would be 0....

**EDIT:**

```
   [SCrl_Wheel setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1000, 0.0)];
```

Add this code ull b getting both sides scrolling ur way :) I tested it ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.But by making [SCrl_Wheel setContentSize:CGSizeMake(-100000,50)];
 It stops the scrolling behavinour

Answer (score 1):

To add Left Side scrolling effect, you can create a scrollview with very large width and then set its initial contentOffset to midpoint of contentwidth of scrollview :

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100000, 60);
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width/2, 0);
```

Comment: it is not scrolling if i use this

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used for scrolling left:

```
HorizontalScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,yourView.frame.size.width,tbv.frame.size.height)];
        [HorizontalScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(930,340)];
        [HorizontalScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // color is set just to know where the scroll view is , remove this line afterwards.
        [self.view addSubview:HorizontalScroll];
        [HorizontalScroll addSubview:yourView];
```