# Infinite UIScrollView gets strange behavior in iOS4.3 not iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've implemented an infinite UIScrollView that contains UIViews. When scrolling in iOS5 (simulator and iphone) it works beautifully. But in iOS 4.3 (sim and phone) it kinda goes a bit crazy and scrolls passed more views than it should (about 10-15x more views than in iOS5). And to make it more strange it works as expected if I drag slowly so it doesn't continue scroll after I release.

The setup is kinda simple, I extend the UIScrollView class. And add UIView with a width of about 1500pt, in this I add my UIViews I want to scroll over. When scrolling the views are added and removed if they are off screen.

I think my problem lies with in this code:

```
 - (void)recenterIfNecessary {
    CGPoint currentOffset = [self contentOffset];
    CGFloat contentWidth = [self contentSize].width;
    CGFloat centerOffsetX = (contentWidth - [self bounds].size.width) / 2.0;
    CGFloat distanceFromCenter = fabs(currentOffset.x - centerOffsetX);
    UIView *image;

    if (distanceFromCenter > (contentWidth / 4.0)) {
        // Recenter the ScrollView so we never reach the edge
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(centerOffsetX, currentOffset.y);
        // Move visiblePhotos to new position to adjust to new contentOffset
        for (image in visiblePhotos) {
            CGPoint center = image.center;
            center.x += (centerOffsetX - currentOffset.x);
            image.center = center;
        }
    }
}
```

`recenterIfNecessary` is invoked here:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];    
    [self recenterIfNecessary];
    [self tileImagesFromMinX:minVisibleX toMaxX:maxVisibleX];
    //....
}
```

I've tried logging positions and offsets to try find a pattern with the difference between iOS4 & 5 with luck.

I got the concept and some code from http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#advanced-scrollview-techniques (they use iOS5).

**EDIT**

Photos (that are put in the visiblePhotos array) are created with this methods:

```
 - (CGFloat)placeNewImageOnRight:(CGFloat)rightEdge {
    imageIndex = imageIndex < 0 ? ([reportItems count] - 1) : (imageIndex >= [reportItems count]  ? 0 : imageIndex);

    UIView *image = [self createItemContainer:[reportItems objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
    [visiblePhotos addObject:image];

    CGRect frame = [image frame];
    frame.origin.x = rightEdge;
    frame.origin.y = [imageContainerView bounds].size.height - frame.size.height;

    [image setFrame:frame];

    imageIndex += 1;

    return CGRectGetMaxX(frame);
}

- (CGFloat)placeNewImageOnLeft:(CGFloat)leftEdge {
    imageIndex = imageIndex < 0 ? ([reportItems count] - 1) : (imageIndex >= [reportItems count] ? 0 : imageIndex);

    UIView *image = [self createItemContainer:[reportItems objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
    [visiblePhotos insertObject:image atIndex:0];

    CGRect frame = [image frame];
    frame.origin.x = leftEdge - frame.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = [imageContainerView bounds].size.height - frame.size.height;
    [image setFrame:frame];

    imageIndex -= 1;

    return CGRectGetMinX(frame);
}
```

`[self createItemContainer:[reportItems objectAtIndex:imageIndex]]` creates a UIVeiw that contains a photo`.

The left and right methods are basically the same and are invoked by the method below. And `tileImagesFromMinX` is invoked on every frame by `- (void)layoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)tileImagesFromMinX:(CGFloat)minVisibleX toMaxX:(CGFloat)maxVisibleX {
    if ([visiblePhotos count] == 0) {
        [self placeNewImageOnRight:minVisibleX];
    }

    UIView *lastImage = [visiblePhotos lastObject];
    CGFloat rightEdge = CGRectGetMaxX([lastImage frame]);
    while (rightEdge < maxVisibleX) {
        rightEdge = [self placeNewImageOnRight:rightEdge];
    }

    UIView *firstImage = [visiblePhotos objectAtIndex:0];
    CGFloat leftEdge = CGRectGetMinX([firstImage frame]);
    while (leftEdge > minVisibleX) {
        leftEdge = [self placeNewImageOnLeft:leftEdge];
    } 

    lastImage = [visiblePhotos lastObject];
    while ([lastImage frame].origin.x > maxVisibleX) {
        [lastImage removeFromSuperview];
        [visiblePhotos removeLastObject];
        lastImage = [visiblePhotos lastObject];
    }    

    firstImage = [visiblePhotos objectAtIndex:0];
    while (CGRectGetMaxX([firstImage frame]) < minVisibleX) {
        [firstImage removeFromSuperview];
        [visiblePhotos removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        firstImage = [visiblePhotos objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want your `visiblePhotos` to scroll off the edge or wrap around or what? Where is the `visiblePhotos` array created?

Comment: I updated the question. My goal is to have and endless scroll. So a user can scroll both ways to infinity, never reaching the end. And all photos are rearranged in the proper order.

Comment: Do the photos loop around? I don't know where `visiblePhotos` comes from.

Comment: The photos loop around. `visiblePhotos` is a NSMutableArray declared in my ScrollView subclass's init method. photos are only added/removed from it from `placeNewImageOnLeft`, `placeNewImageOnRight` and  `(void)tileImagesFromMinX:(CGFloat)minVisibleX toMaxX:(CGFloat)maxVisibleX`

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice the edit. I'll take another look.

Answer (score 6):

I've done a bunch of investigating and determined that you can't just set `self.contentOffset = ...;` and expect the scroll view to scroll/decelerate properly in iOS 4.3. So, even without the image tiling (and in fact you will notice this more clearly if you remove your images and just put a background on your image container view), your implementation of `recenterIfNecessary` will not work under 4.3 (this also affects the sample code on the developer site!).

Unfortunately, it seems the only way to work around this is to override `-setContentOffset:` and modify the offset there before calling `super`. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling) for some guidance on how to get that working correctly. I hope for your sake that this method will also work in iOS 5...

Comment: I removed the call for `recenterIfNecessary` and overrode the `setContentOffset` and only handling contentOffset in it. Now it kinda works. Some times it jumps around a bit. But it definite improvement. I'll try to play around with the math a bit more.