# Create an omnidirectional scrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, uiscrollview

I want to create an omnidirectional scrollview that works pretty much like the one in the "Wall of Sound" app. As in, the user should be able to pull into any direction and never get to an end. I want to keep the move to be smooth (and not see the pages change as you would in a standard scrollview). Does anyone know how that can be done? Or would I need OpenGL for that?

Comment: Tell us more about what the content you need to display is.  Is it just a recurssion of images or something else?

Comment: The view will be initialised with some images (from a URL) and when the user moves it into any direction, more images from that URL will be loaded. All the time, the images will be different.

Comment: You can try using one of the ScrollView's delegates, like `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` to determine if the scrollView's content offset is close to it's size and if so, extend it.

Comment: Wouldn't that leave me without RAM at some point? Is it not possible to reinitialize it in that current position?

Answer (score 0):

Create a 3x3 grid of views, each the size of the viewport. As the scrollview moves into another section, rearrange the views to constantly put the viewport in the center. In most cases 3x3 is sufficient, but if redrawing the views is expensive, you may want to use a larger grid (5x5 for instance). This requires that you have some mechanism for splitting up your full view into tiles.

You can implement the same thing using `CALayer` if you like. If you go that way, you should consider instead using `CATiledLayer`. See Matt Long's quick introduction on [CIMGF](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/).

Comment: So you're saying I should create a 960x2880 scrollView composed of 9 UIViews/UIImageViews and then redraw those when the user moves out of the view?

Comment: I usually rearrange them. If you're going right, then you move the left-hand views over to the far right ahead of the scrolling. At any given time there are only 9 views in the scrollview, but they keep moving around.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do that. Would you be willing to write some sample code if I don't manage? :-)

Comment: Give it a shot. If you have too much trouble, drop me a note with a little more detail on what you're trying to do (my email is in my profile). It's a worthwhile blog post, and I have some similar code lying around. First look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling. The Wall of Sound app looks like CATiledLayer at first guess.