# UIScrollView paging works fine in simulator but application crashes in device after 15-20 pages

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have used UIScrollView with paging enabled. I have more then 1000 images and I am adding 12 images per page. I am loading 12 images every time when page is scrolled. But after scrolling 15-20 page application is getting crashed in device. It works fine with simulator. Please let me know what can be the issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: excessive memory usage..

Comment: have you tried to log memory warnings? Your app receives two levels of memory warnings which you could log. Make sure that you are not exceeding the memory limit.

Comment: ok. but what can be the solution for that?

Comment: release old images loaded when no more displayed in screen, you cannot just load new images...

Comment: Excessive Memory Usage can be the problem. Are you using XCode 4? I mean to say is it ARC enabled ? If not try to free the memory on the go. Check out your log, you'll definitely be getting some memory warnings/errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide any code but it looks like this is a case of bad
memory management, as all the comments suggest.

One way to solve this would be to allocate just three pages (each holding 12 images)
and then joggle with their positions and contents according to user interaction.

I think you'll find these two links helpful:

[Creating Circular and Infinite UIScrollViews](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html)

[UIScrollView Infinite Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling)