# Backward Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Hi I have 10 images in UIScrollview now i can scroll forward like from 1 to 2,3,4,etc but in my project i need to scroll images backward direction also like from 1 to 10 to left hand side 
this is my code

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{
 CGFloat pageWidth = cardsScrollView.frame.size.width;
 NSUInteger page = floor((self.cardsScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    if(page + 1 == [flashCardArry count]){
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [flashCardArry count]; ++i) {
            int nElements = [flashCardArry count] - i;
            int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
            [flashCardArry exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
        }
    [self.cardsScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.cardsScrollView.frame.size.width * 0 , 0, self.cardsScrollView.frame.size.width, self.cardsScrollView.frame.size.height)  animated:NO];
    }


-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    CGFloat pageWidth = cardsScrollView.frame.size.width;

NSUInteger page = floor((self.cardsScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
```

Comment: So as far as I understand you need to have cyclic scrollview? I mean, user should be able to scroll from left to right and from right to left freely?

Comment: Yes Kilew exactly i need what you thought

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView Infinite Scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by adding the imageViews from 10 to 1 on your scrollView and then you have se the contentOffset of you scrollview to point to the last image which is image 1.
So user wont be able to scroll right at first, he can scroll to left for next images.

Comment: Thank you but i need to scroll in both directions when i reach last image than i move to 1 now i want to go for last in back ward direction

Comment: @user3205449 So when you are on the image 1 it would get scroll to get to last scroll. You don't have to do any additional setup for that it will work for both direction.

Answer (score 0):

So. In case if you want cyclic scrollview you would need next things:

1) hide scrollView indicators

```
scrl.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrl.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

2) Add one item to beginning of the scroll view, and one item at the end

```
   [5'] | [0][1][2][3][4][5] | [0']
        | --- full_size---   |
```

3) Once user scrolls to 5' item we updating content offset by adding full_size

4) Once user scrolls to 0' item we updating content offset by subtracting full_size

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
   // First item
   if (contentOffset.x < page_size) { // We are now faking last page
      scrollView.contentOffset += full_size; // Jumping to actual last page
   }

   // Last item
   if (contentOffset.x > full_size) { // We are now faking first page
      scrollView.contentOffset -= full_size; // Jumping to actual first page
   }

}
```

5) To decrease amount of jumps (especially on the borders), you can add more 2 or more fake items from both side

Comment: Actually there's already answers in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling

Comment: hi here we used page_size and full_size. what is these variables?

Comment: page_size is just size(in this example - width) of the one page, if you have pageable content. full_size - is the total width of all pages.